# react-testing-library - How do you test for the existence of text if it is wrapped contained in other child html tags?

Tags: react-testing-library

Given the example html:

`const fragment = (<div>Hello <span>world</span>. How are you <b>doing</b>?</div>)`

Is there a way to ignore all the child html tags with react-testing-library?

like so (psuedo-code)

`expect(fragment).toHaveTextContent(/hello world. how are you doing/)`

Answer (score 3):

**First solution:**

You can use `@testing-library/jest-dom` this library provides a set of custom jest matchers that you can use to extend jest and react-testing-library. Here is the link:

https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tocontainelement

```
<span data-testid="ancestor"><span data-testid="descendant"></span></span>
```

---

```
const ancestor = getByTestId('ancestor')
const descendant = getByTestId('descendant')
const nonExistantElement = getByTestId('does-not-exist')

expect(ancestor).toContainElement(descendant)
expect(descendant).not.toContainElement(ancestor)
expect(ancestor).not.toContainElement(nonExistantElement)
```

**Second solution:**

```
import { render, within } from '@testing-library/react'

const { getByLabelText } = render(<MyComponent />)
const signinModal = getByLabelText('Sign In')
within(signinModal).getByPlaceholderText('Username')
```